# Why function composing not available in IntFunction

Tags: java, function, lambda, method-reference

I was reading the function composition section from Chap-3 Modern Java in action.

I am unable to understand why I can't compose IntFunctions. Am I making a silly mistake or is there any design decision behind this ?

Here is my code with error in comments

```
package mja;

import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.IntFunction;

public class AppTest2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        IntFunction<Integer> plusOne = x -> x+1;
        IntFunction<Integer> square = x -> (int) Math.pow(x,2);
        
        // Compiler can't find method andThen in IntFunction and not allowing to compile
        IntFunction<Integer> incrementThenSquare = plusOne.andThen(square); 
        int result = incrementThenSquare.apply(1);

        Function<Integer, Integer> plusOne2 = x -> x + 1;
        Function<Integer, Integer> square2 = x -> (int) Math.pow(x,2);
        
        //Below works perfectly
        Function<Integer, Integer> incrementThenSquare2 = plusOne2.andThen(square2);
        int result2 = incrementThenSquare2.apply(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking from a conceptual point of view? The `IntFunction` interface does not declare such a method, so you can't call it.

Comment: Hi @SotiriosDelimanolis, yes I am asking from functional point fo view. I don't undersand why this method is not added to IntFunction.

Comment: @GauthamM they are related and `Function` is also a functional interface, but has default methods in it.. So the question is legitimate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, in your example, using `IntFunction<Integer>` is not really an optimal choice, and this is probably the reason why you're stuck.

When trying to work on a function that takes an `int` and returns an `int`, you want to use `IntUnaryOperator` which has the method `andThen(IntUnaryOperator)` you're looking for.

The reason why it has not been implemented in `IntFunction<R>` is that you can't be sure your function will return the input necessary for the next `IntFunction<R>` which is an `int` of course.

Your case is straightforward but imagine having a `IntFunction<List<String>>` instead, you can't chain the functions because `IntFunction<R>` does not accept a `List<String>` as an input.

---

Here is your corrected example

```java
IntUnaryOperator plusOne = x -> x + 1;
IntUnaryOperator square = x -> (int) Math.pow(x, 2);

IntUnaryOperator incrementThenSquare = plusOne.andThen(square);
int result = incrementThenSquare.applyAsInt(1);

System.out.println("result = " + result); // result = 4
```